# Choosing smaller deltas for epsilon delta proof

Tags: real-analysis

When Proving $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous for $(2,\infty)$ I know the convention is for $k \in (2,\infty)$ to pick $\delta=\text{min}\{\frac{k}{2},\frac{k^2\epsilon}{2}\},\text{for}\epsilon>0$ but will there be any trouble picking $\delta=\text{min}\{\frac{k}{2},\frac{k^2\epsilon}{2k}\}$  since the delta is smaller than the previous? I'm confident this is correct, bI just need reassurance.

Comment: If the $\epsilon$ constraint is satisfied  under the 1st $\delta$ then it will also be satisfied for any smaller value.  The second $\delta$ qualifies.  So, for whatever your reason for choosing the second $\delta$, the corresponding $\epsilon$ constraint **must** still be satisfied.

Comment: So its still correct right, if I used it in a proof.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's to see a proof of your assertion.

**Definition:** We say $f$ is continuous at $a$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

**Claim:** Suppose $\delta(\epsilon)$ is chosen to satisfy continuity. Then $\delta_1(\epsilon)<\delta(\epsilon)$ also suffices.

Proof: $|x-a|<\delta_1 \implies |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$